# Error when converting batch file to shell script and executing TFS commands

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a batch file that executes these commands:

```
set repodir=D:\Folder
cd /d %repodir%
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
tf undo * /recursive /noprompt
tf get
```

I want to achieve same functionality from shell script. I am able to change the directory path to wherever code is present

**Problems:**

1. command **call** is not found - read that I need to use `.` operator in shell script. Tried this but not working. Error is "@echo command not found" in vcvarsall.bat ( the first line in that file is @echo off )

   `. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64`
2. Since calling batch file is failing in step 2, command **tf** is not found

   `tf undo * /recursive /noprompt
    tf get`

**Environment:** I am trying to run the shell script using **cygwin** on Windows Server 2008

Comment: @JonTofte-Hansen space should be there. But thats not the problem. I get error at line 1 ( in vccarsall.bat ) where ```@echo off``` is there

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the 'call' because that is for calling one bat file from another.
2. Specify the full path for tf.exe. Of course that will vary depending on the version of TFS you have installed.

Comment: RGuggisberg is correct. You should have the following in the batch file: set repodir=D:\Folder
cd /d %repodir%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe undo * /recursive /noprompt"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe get /all"